# Can't set headers after they are sent : multiple middleware executions concurency

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

In my main express.js config file, I `use` two custom error middleware functions:

```
const error = require('../middlewares/error');

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(error.notFound);

// if error is not an instanceOf APIError, convert it.
app.use(error.converter);
```

I use [boom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boom) to unify error messages. this is my error middleware:

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Error responder. Send stacktrace only during development
   * @public
   */
  responder: (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.output.payload.statusCode);
    res.json(err.output.payload);
    res.end();
  },

  /**
   * If error is not a Boom error, convert it.
   * @public
   */
  converter: (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (env !== 'development') {
      delete err.stack;
    }
    if (err.isBoom) {
      return module.exports.responder(err, req, res);
    }
    if (err.name === 'MongoError' && err.code === 11000) {
      const boomedError = boom.conflict('This email already exists');
      boomedError.output.payload.stack = err ? err.stack : undefined;
      return module.exports.responder(boomedError, req, res);
    }
    const boomedError = boom.boomify(err, { statusCode: 422 });
    return module.exports.responder(boomedError, req, res);
  },

  /**
   * Catch 404 and forward to error responder
   * @public
   */
  notFound: (req, res) => {
    const err = boom.notFound('Not Found');
    return module.exports.responder(err, req, res);
  },
};
```

My problem is, when I make a "register" action with an existing email, the `responder()` is executed three times. One for my boom.conflict error, but then also one for "not found". (even though I've done `res.end()`.

This is the register logic:

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    validationResult(req).throw();
    const user = new User(req.body);
    const token = generateTokenResponse(user, user.token());
    const userTransformed = user.transform();
    user.tokens.push({ kind: 'jwt', token });
    user.activationId = uuidv1();
    await user.save();
    res.status(httpStatus.CREATED);
    sendValidationEmail(user.activationId);
    return res.json({ user: userTransformed });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(converter(err, req, res, next));
  }
};
```

`user.save()` triggers this by the way:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function save(next) {
  try {
    if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

    const rounds = env === 'test' ? 1 : 10;

    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, rounds);
    this.password = hash;

    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(converter(err));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `res.end()` just tells the response stream that you're done sending data. You don't need that in this case because calling `res.json()` will do it for you.

However, that isn't the same as telling Express that you're done with handling the request. Just because you've sent a response doesn't necessarily mean you've no work left to do.

The way you tell Express that you've finished is by not calling `next()`. Express assumes you've finished by default and will only continue executing the middleware/routing chain if you call `next()`.

So this line:

```
return next(converter(err, req, res, next));
```

should just be:

```
converter(err, req, res, next);
```

Likewise your other call to `converter()` shouldn't be calling `next()` either.

Comment: ah you mean `next(converter..())` will run both convert AND any other middleware that i `app.use()`?

Comment: Don't confuse the Express middleware/routing chain with the JS call stack. When `responder()` exits the call stack will return to the function that called it (`converter()`), which will in turn return to where it was called. That is where `next()` is being called.

Comment: Perfect. Answer ready tobe accepted. Do you mind adding an example of a useful scenario where we need to `next(someMethod())` ? I fail to understand what happens with the call stack there.

Comment: It's equivalent to `var arg = someMethod(); next(arg);`. If you call `next(arg)` then the `arg` is treated as an error by Express. Unless `someMethod()` returns an error then that line makes no sense, you should just call `someMethod(); next();` instead (assuming you do actually need to call `next()`, which you don't in your case).

Comment: in a theoretical scenario, why would I need to call a method (which performs a `res.end()`) and a next?

Comment: It rarely happens in practice but in theory it would be because you have another handler in the chain that does some 'work' that needs to be performed after you've already responded. Perhaps something that takes a long time to complete, or maybe clean-up work like deleting files. Of course you wouldn't be able to communicate any errors if the response is already sent but in our hypothetical scenario we can just assume that doesn't matter.

Comment: just to note that I replaced `converter(err, req, res, next)` with `next(err, req, res, next)` and the middleware is triggered also perfectly.

Comment: Just using `next(err)` should be enough. The other arguments will be handled automatically.

Comment: According to the documentation error Middleware methods take obligatory four arguments.

Comment: Error middleware must take 4 arguments but calling `next` with an error does not. When you call `next` you are not directly invoking the next piece of middleware in the chain, you're just telling Express to do it for you. If you pass an error with `next(err)` it tells Express to invoke your error middleware and Express will ensure it is passed the appropriate 4 arguments.

Comment: How will express know which argument I'm passing it? I thought the total number of arguments helps it understand it is an error handling Middleware.